# Different posts content on different pages with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making a simple info web-site based on wordpress, but I dont have any experience. In the menu I have "Projects", "Partners" and "News". I need to make so, that the person that I make the site for, can add more partners for example in future or adding projects (And almost every day news). So I was told that I should use categories and for example if my "client" want to add anything, he creates a new post with the apropriate category. If he want to add new partner he creates a post with category "Partner", and it visualises in the Partners page.

p.s.: Sorry if you get confused by my explanation Im very tired but I need to finish that quick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can categorize posts by the categories you create and you can link to the categories using menus. See https://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/categories/ and you'll get a better understanding.

Comment: So how do I asign a given category posts to its menu?

Comment: See ahttps://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/ go to Admin > Appearance > Menus > Select the active menu and choose the categories which you've already created.